# MVC C# weird characters while debugging on localhost

Tags: c#, debugging, model-view-controller, localhost

So I have reinstalled the Windows and all that and I have a problem regarding debugging of an MVC project. 
Project is in VS 2010, running on IIS 8.0.
When deployed, everything is fine, but when I'm debugging locally there are some problems. Some weird characters get injected in random places and break up my views entirely.
[image: img]

I have changed my character set, I've checked with hex editor my views, there are no weird characters in there. I've reinstalled IIS.
Still nothing works.

```html
<met�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������a property="og:image" content="https://content.xxxxx.hr/logo.png">
```

Output I want is the same one, but without the weird ? characters.

Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: That's a character decoder error "replacement character". So there's some invalid data being given to a decoder somewhere.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I just found out what was wrong...  XML file was the cause. It lose encoding at the top. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> for future people that get this annoyance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web.config file lost encoding at the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

for a future reference if anyone else encounters this issue.